# Como traçar uma rota usando Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

Tenho um tela onde se encontra o Google Maps e nela eu quero que pegue a posição atual do usuário e faça uma rota automaticamente ate o ponto de geolocalização que eu vou deixar definida "Fixa" no código. Como fazer?

Answer (score 4):

Não entendi exatamente o que você precisa, mas vou tentar responder.

Opção 1 - Se você tem um controle de GPS e quer mostrar no mapa a rota que o usuário fez do ponto A para o ponto B, basta você pegar cada LatLng (latitude/longitude), adicionar num List, e usando Polylines, você consegue montar o trajeto no mapa, quanto mais pontos (latitude/longitude) você tiver, melhor, pq se só tiver 2 vai aparecer uma linha reta ligando os 2 pontos.

```
List<LatLng> decodedPath = null;
decodedPath.add(new LatLng(0,0)); // latitude e longitude
decodedPath.add(new LatLng(1,1)); // latitude e longitude
decodedPath.add(new LatLng(2,2)); // latitude e longitude
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(decodedPath).color(Color.GRAY));
```

Opção 2 - Se você só tem o local atual dele do GPS, e o local de origem/destino, mas não tem o trajeto todo que o usuário fez nesse meio tempo, você precisa usar a API do Google para que ele faça o trajeto, e só depois você pode mostrar essa informação no mapa. Vou colocar um exemplo que está funcionando para mim.

Com o mapa pronto, acrescente as duas linhas abaixo para iniciar a chamada da API e preencher o trajeto no mapa

```
String urlTopass = makeURL(latLngOld.latitude, latLngOld.longitude, latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude); // lat origem, lon origem, lat destino, lon destino

new connectAsyncTask(urlTopass).execute();
```

Pega o link para que o app possa usar a API do google

```
public String makeURL(double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat, double destlog) {
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
    urlString.append("?origin=");// from
    urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelog));
    urlString.append("&destination=");// to
    urlString.append(Double.toString(destlat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString(destlog));
    urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");
    return urlString.toString();
}
```

Inicia a chamada da API, aqui ele vai pegar todos os pontos necessários para ir do ponto A para o ponto B

```
private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String url;

    connectAsyncTask(String urlPass) {
        url = urlPass;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            drawPath(result);
        }
    }
}

public class JSONParser {

    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }

    public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            org.apache.http.HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            json = sb.toString();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        return json;

    }
}
```

Atualiza o mapa com o caminho passado pela API do Google

```
public void drawPath(String result) {
    if (line != null) {
        //myMap.clear();
    }

    try {
        // Tranform the string into a json object
        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
        JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
        String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);

        for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 1; z++) {
            LatLng src = list.get(z);
            LatLng dest = list.get(z + 1);
            line = myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude), new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude))
                    .width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } 
}
```

Decodifica o retorno da API para pontos LatLng para que o app possa mostrar no mapa

```
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;

        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);

        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)), (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

Comment: Descula pela minha ignorancia...

Comment: Desculpa pela minha ignorancia... Mas eu me confundi na sua resposta... É assim, eu defini o Ponto em um shopping de Sao Paulo, vamos supor que o usuario está no Rio de Janeiro, eu quero que automaticamente apareça uma rota do local onde o usuario está até o ponto fixo onde eu defini que no caso é o Shopping.

Comment: Use a segunda resposta, que utiliza a API do Google, chamando a função "makeURL" e a "connectAsyncTask", você só precisa passar a latitude e longitude correta na chamada do makeURL, São 4 parâmetros latitude/longitude do ponto A e latitude/longitude do ponto B